# buildings aren't extruding in arcgis

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I'm new to this, but I'm trying to make a 3D map of a street . I have a geojson file that specifies the real estate parcels and their data and elevations of buildings, When the page renders, I get the parcels as seen from the angle I designated, but the buildings don't extrude properly.

HTML

```
<div id="map" style="width:100vw;height:100vh"></div>
```

build.geojson

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": { "height": 100 },
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [104.62904829679594, 28.770551732445085],
            [104.62903758417833, 28.770551271134227],
            [104.62902697472938, 28.77054989164433],
            [104.62901657062415, 28.770547607260685],
            [104.62900647206008, 28.770544439983208],
            [104.6289967762921, 28.770540420314582],
            [104.62898757669596, 28.770535586966528],
            [104.62897896186888, 28.770529986486927],
            [104.6289710147765, 28.770523672811578],
            [104.62896381195364, 28.770516706744754],
            [104.62895742276743, 28.770509155373603],
            [104.62895190874912, 28.770501091422084],
            [104.62894732300157, 28.770492592550568],
            [104.62894370968789, 28.770483740607922],
            [104.62894110360604, 28.770474620843277],
            [104.62893952985377, 28.770465321085002],
            [104.62893900358688, 28.770455930894908],
            [104.62893952987334, 28.77044654070565],
            [104.62894110364445, 28.77043724094988],
            [104.62894370974364, 28.7704281211893],
            [104.62894732307251, 28.770419269252127],
            [104.62895190883253, 28.770410770387276],
            [104.62895742286011, 28.770402706443356],
            [104.62896381205206, 28.770395155080458],
            [104.62897101487683, 28.77038818902221],
            [104.62897896196732, 28.770381875355437],
            [104.62898757678866, 28.770376274884086],
            [104.62899677637554, 28.770371441543634],
            [104.62900647213104, 28.77036742188168],
            [104.62901657067988, 28.770364254609667],
            [104.62902697476777, 28.770361970230084],
            [104.62903758419792, 28.77036059074269],
            [104.62904829679594, 28.770360129432685],
            [104.62905900939396, 28.77036059074269],
            [104.62906961882408, 28.770361970230084],
            [104.62908002291199, 28.770364254609667],
            [104.62909012146083, 28.77036742188168],
            [104.62909981721633, 28.770371441543634],
            [104.6291090168032, 28.770376274884086],
            [104.62911763162455, 28.770381875355437],
            [104.62912557871502, 28.77038818902221],
            [104.62913278153981, 28.770395155080458],
            [104.62913917073176, 28.770402706443356],
            [104.62914468475935, 28.770410770387276],
            [104.62914927051936, 28.770419269252127],
            [104.62915288384823, 28.7704281211893],
            [104.62915548994742, 28.77043724094988],
            [104.62915706371854, 28.77044654070565],
            [104.629157590005, 28.770455930894908],
            [104.6291570637381, 28.770465321085002],
            [104.62915548998583, 28.770474620843277],
            [104.62915288390398, 28.770483740607922],
            [104.6291492705903, 28.770492592550568],
            [104.62914468484276, 28.770501091422084],
            [104.62913917082446, 28.770509155373603],
            [104.62913278163823, 28.770516706744754],
            [104.62912557881538, 28.770523672811578],
            [104.62911763172299, 28.770529986486927],
            [104.62910901689591, 28.770535586966528],
            [104.62909981729976, 28.770540420314582],
            [104.62909012153179, 28.770544439983208],
            [104.62908002296773, 28.770547607260685],
            [104.62906961886247, 28.77054989164433],
            [104.62905900941354, 28.770551271134227],
            [104.62904829679594, 28.770551732445085]
          ]
        ],
        "type": "Polygon"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

JS

```
     const buildLayer = new GeoJSONLayer({
        url: "./yibin/build.geojson",
        id: "buildLayer",
        outFields: ["*"],
        visualVariables: [
          {
            type: "size",
            field: "height",
          },
        ],
        popupTemplate: {
          // autocasts as new PopupTemplate()
          title: "popup-title",
          content: [
            {
              type: "fields",
              fieldInfos: [
                {
                  fieldName: "__OBJECTID",
                  label: "ObjectId",
                },
                {
                  fieldName: "height",
                  label: "height",
                },
              ],
            },
          ],
        },
        renderer: {
          type: "simple",
          symbol: {
            type: "polygon-3d",
            symbolLayers: [
              {
                castShadows: true,
                type: "extrude",
                material: { color: new Color("red") },
              },
            ],
          },
        },
      });
     const map = new Map({
        basemap: "topo-vector",
        ground: "world-elevation",
      });
      const view = new SceneView({
        map: map,
        container: "map",
        center: [104.62123200508927, 28.742935651635648],
        zoom: 18,
      });
```

Comment: You have a problem in your code, the property `visualVariables` should go in `renderer` not in the layer.